# php str_replace hex color

Tags: php, str-replace

how do you replace this string `*#ff00ff Hello World *000000` to `<span style='color:#ff00ff'> Hello World </span>` using str_replace?

Thanks.

Comment: `$string = str_replace('*#ff00ff Hello World *000000', '<span style='color:#ff00ff'> Hello World </span', $string);` Seriously, what are you trying to do? What have you tried and did not work?

Comment: Watch out ' and ".  Thus would have to be
$string = str_replace('*#ff00ff Hello World *000000', "<span style='color:#ff00ff'> Hello World </span>", $string);

But good question where the original problem there is (thus what did not function with str_replace there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = '*#ff00ff Hello World *000000';

$string = preg_replace('/\*#([a-f\d]{6})(.*)\*[a-f\d]+/', "<span style='color:$1'>$2</span>", $string);

echo $string;
```

can also be done like so:

```
$string = '*#ff00ff Hello World *000000';

$string = preg_replace('/\*#([[:xdigit:]]{6})(.*)\*[[:xdigit:]]+/', "<span style='color:$1'>$2</span>", $string);

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '*#ff00ff Hello World *000000';
preg_match('/(#[0-9a-f]{6})/i', $str, $matches);
echo "<span style='color:{$matches[1]}'> Hello World </span>";
```

Comment: oops, forgot the parenthesis.